# using React,Vite,EmailJs,Vercel. i cant send email in production but it works in dev

Tags: reactjs, email, dns, vercel, godaddy-api

Sending an email in my dev works, but it my vercel it doesnt work with a purchesed domain from goDaddy, i make sure i pass the same variables both on dev and production, there is no problems with the env variables.

the error on production is

status:400 bad request
message: The service ID not found. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin

but i do send the right service ID for sure i think the problem is that i am using vercel and with a purchsed domain.